# Unfortunately <app> has stopped working(overflow menu)

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I am a beginner android programmer.I am learning the overflow menu concept by making an app which changes the background color when one of the three items in menu is selsected.  I am not understanding why my app after selecting one item from the option closes and above error is shown.

here is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.awani.overflowmenu;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
  //  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    RelativeLayout main_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);

    //test which item is selected by user
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_red:
            if(item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            main_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_green:
            if(item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            main_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_yellow:
            if(item.isChecked())
                item.setChecked(false);
            else
                item.setChecked(true);
            main_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

}
```

in MainActivity.java,in the function onOptionsItemSelected(Menu menu),I am getting red line under the (RelativeLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.main_view).it says 'Unexpected cast to RelativeLayout.but gradle is built successfully.

I have seen other answers but could not relate to my situation

event log says this :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process:com.awani.overflowmenu, PID: 26829
                                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                                                        at com.awani.overflowmenu.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3201)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:679)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:127)
                                                                        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:340)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1530)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3698)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5682)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: can you post your xml layout for main activity ?

Comment: The exception is "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout" and your code is `(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);` (at least what you've posted here) and yet you don't understand what to do?

Comment: check your xml view id(R.id.main_view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error log suggests

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout

you tried to cast a TextView to a RelativeLayout. This is not possible. Check your layout_main.xml and set android:id for the the RelativeLayout. Then use that id to get a reference in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide `menu/main_view.xml` file?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
```

This sentence describes the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout**

your `R.id.main_view` is not a relativeLayout it's an AppCompatTextView.

change this line

```
RelativeLayout main_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
```

with this

```
AppCompatTextView main_view = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
```